# Chromium print-to-pdf adding space above images

Tags: html, django, docker, pdf, chromium

**The background**

I have a simple document making system which is part of a Python Django application. The PDF download uses Chromium's print-to-pdf function running from a Docker container by passing in the URL of the document page from the Django app.

The HTML is edited using TinyMCE.

**The problem**

Large gaps are appearing above some images with no obvious difference between the ones that do and the ones that don't have gaps.

I have put borders around HTML tags with differing colours to try and see what is containing the empty space:

- div: red
- p: green
- span: blue
- img: black
- td: orange

**The evidence**

The offending section of the page looks like this in the browser:

[image]

The resulting PDF looks like this with a big gap in the middle:

[image]

The HTML for that section is:

```html
<div class="content flex None">
    <div class="docsection flex">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header" style="position: relative;">
                <!-- the trigger element if no value set yet -->
                <a href="" id="docsection_title70-btn" class="text-darken-2 inplace-editor-trigger error" style="" data-for="docsection_title70">
                    Add title
                </a>
                <!-- the actual output content if there is any yet -->
                <h2 class="inplace-editor-content
    tooltip
    title" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Click to edit" data-for="docsection_title70">
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="copy tinymce" style="position: relative;">
                <!-- the trigger element if no value set yet -->
                <a href="" id="docsection_content70-btn" class="text-darken-2 inplace-editor-trigger error" style="display: none;" data-for="docsection_content70">
                    Add content
                </a>
                <!-- the actual output content if there is any yet -->
                <div class="inplace-editor-content
    tooltip
   " data-position="top" data-tooltip="Click to edit" data-for="docsection_content70">
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 98.811%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #34495e;">Clients bring briefs</span></strong></h2>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #34495e;">Teams get together</span></strong></h2>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah-image-data" width="848" height="455"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why that gap is there with seemingly no container???

Comment: If I delete the slide/page, add a new one in the same place and add a totally different image (without the title table) I get exactly the same issue...

Comment: Perhaps look into `break-after` and avoiding `display: flex` or `display: grid`. Check out this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/) which helped me deal with some similar spacing issues

Answer (score 0):

After simplifying the HTML the problem went away UNTIL I removed the debugging borders and the empty space in the PDF came right back... Reducing the borders back to just a 1px transparent border on the top parent of the slide retains the fix so this is a very odd bug in Chromium's PDF generation.

So, if you come across a PDF spacing bug then try playing with borders whilst I wait to hear back from the Chromium team.

Cheers

Rich